# Conversion of a currency string in the format "0.0 GBP 0"

Tags: c#

I'm pulling data from an API and I'm trying to see if there is a decent way of pulling apart the string that's being returned.

Ideally I want to put this into a database as a decimal value.

### UPDATE:

I'm interested in the 0.0 and I'd wondered if there was a decimal.parse that could strip it down like I could do with the date/time as noted below:

```
DateTime updated;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("Wed Jun 05 08:06:17 UTC 2013",Config.dateTimeFormat,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out updated))
{
// Yeah!!
}
```

However what has been noted below is that the trim and strip will do the job. What I'm really after is a high performance solution to the problem as it's part of a delta sync routine.

Comment: Use a regex? Give some examples of what inputs you have and what you expect to pull out of them. What's that trailing `0` for?

Comment: Why do people feel the need to down vote a question?

Comment: Because it's not a good question and isn't well framed. Read the FAQ on how to ask good questions. You question should include a clear explanation of what you are trying to achieve and some demonstration of what you have tried. Your question is vague (we assume you want `0.0`, but you don't explicitly say that) and includes no indication of what you've tried. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Provided more information on what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want to parse the first part in the string which represents the numeric value? Then you could use `String.Split` and take the first:

```
string text = "0.0 GBP 0";
string value = text.Trim().Split()[0]; // 0.0
decimal pounds = decimal.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```